# SamlError Single Sign-On Error with google

Tags: apex, single-sign-on

I am working on enabling SSO for our organization with Google.

I setup the Single Sign-On Configuration.

SAML Identity Type: Assertion contains the Federation ID from the User object

SAML Identity Location: dentity is in the NameIdentifier element of the Subject statement

Service Provider Initiated Request Binding:
HTTP POST

Below is the error I continue to receive. How can I better debug this to understand whether or not this is a Salesforce or Google issue?

Domain with Error Message: https://company.my.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/saml/SamlError

[image]

```
    <saml2p:StatusMessage>Invalid request, ACS Url in request
        https://company.my.salesforce.com?sc=0LE4x000000LRkV doesn't match configured ACS Url
        https://company.my.salesforce.com?so=00D4x000003wk2I.</saml2p:StatusMessage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the Single Sign On setup you have created, there is a button called "SAML Assertion Validator" that should give you more detail on where it failed.

Btw, since you are using Google, have you considered using Auth Providers?
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I cannot get that one to work either. SSO has been a bit of a nightmare for me so far! I have no idea how to use the SAML Assetion Validator: Enter your SAML response in base64-encoded, deflated and base64-encoded, or plain XML format into the field below, and click Validate.

Comment: another way I would tackle this is to download a chrome plugin named 'SAML-Tracer' that should also give you a good idea on where it fails

Comment: <saml2p:StatusMessage>Invalid request, ACS Url in request
            https://company.my.salesforce.com?sc=0LE4x000000LRkV doesn't match configured ACS Url
            https://company.my.salesforce.com?so=00D4x000003wk2I.</saml2p:StatusMessage>

Comment: ah ok, check your configuration in Google, and update the Entity Id to match what you put in the Single Sign On setup

Comment: Our Entity ID for the single sign-on is: https://includedhealth.my.salesforce.com

Do I need to copy this and paste this somewhere in google?